# Binary search with vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, binary-search

I have a struct where data is defined as:

```
typedef struct contacts 
{
    string name;   //{jhonathan , anderson , felicia}
    string nickName; //{jhonny  , andy , felic}
    string phoneNumber; // {13453514 ,148039 , 328490}
    string carrier;  // {atandt , coolmobiles , atandt }
    string address; // {1bcd , gfhs ,jhtd }

} contactDetails;

vector <contactDetails> proContactFile;
```

Here I want to do a binary search for the `name`.if the searched name is available then i want to display the relevant contact details for that name(`nickname,phone number ,carrier ,address` ).How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use an associative container such as `std::map<std::string, contactDetails>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
auto cmpFn = [](const contacts &c1, const contacts &c2) {return c1.name < c2.name;};

// 1. vector must be sorted
std::sort(proContactFile.begin(), proContactFile.end(), cmpFn);

// 2. what to find
contacts findme; findme.name = "cat";

// 3. find
auto it = std::lower_bound(proContactFile.begin(), proContactFile.end(), findme, cmpFn);
bool found = it != proContactFile.end() && it->name == findme.name;
```

Comment: Yeah this is working.This is not bubble sorting though??I need to search the name using bubble sort